# DCEVM code redefinition is disabled

Tags: java, redefinition, dcevm, guidewire

I'm working with GuideWire - it's an out of box online insurance implementation. It's java based and has its own IDE. Firstly `DCEVM` worked perfectly, increasing my productivity dramatically. But couple days ago, it has stopped working, supplying me with

> "Classes hasn't been reloaded as coderedefenition is disabled".

I've already tried everything and asked everybody for help, but nobody has faced this problem.

Comment: hi can you confirm what java jdk version are you running? and guidewire platform version?

Answer (score 0):

More than likely this is because the version of java you have started the app server with is now different and doesn't have the DCEVM applied to it.

You need to double click and run the applicable dcevm.jar and then it will throw up a UI for you to view and select the appropriate JDK's to apply the Dynamic Code Evolution VM changes onto.

Full video showing how to do that is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLFxCRaVh-g